# WMV videos playing too fast when skipping

Tags: video, playback, wmv

When I'm playing a WMV video and I skip to some part (clicking in the video timeline), it starts playing in fast-forward and only resume normal speed after 2 or 3 seconds. This happens only with WMV files and with every file (so it's not a problem with a specific video). It's extremely annoying.

I'm starting to think this is a video driver problem, or is it just the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have the same problem you have described.  A more accurate description of my particular problem (just to make sure it is the same as yours) is:

> When seeking (jumping timecodes) during WMV playback, when the video resumes from the new timecode, the video will temporarily speed up (it starts a few seconds behind the seeking point), while the audio properly aligns with the seeking point.  When the video finally catches up with the audio, the playback resumes properly synchronized.

In my case, I found that the problem will only manifests itself in DirectShow-based media players (Windows Media Player, Media Player Classic, etc...).  The *only* media player that I've used which does NOT have this problem is [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), which uses completely self-contained codecs for playback.

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility that your files aren't indexed.  Try using:

http://www.jhepple.com/wmvindexer.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's the video catching up to the point in time of the audio. There is probably a reference frame in the compression and it has to start at that point and reconstruct to the point where you clicked. (That's an educated guess)
Maybe if you tried VLC or MPC HC this would go away.